# Why is the side chain of lysine more basic?

Tags: acid-base, amino-acids

According to the images below, the NH3+ on the side chain of lysine is less acidic than the NH3+ closer to the COO-. Why is this? Wouldn't the NH3+ have an intramolecular H-bond with a negatively charged oxygen on the carboxylic acid group, stabilizing it?

One possible explanation I thought of is the carbons on the side chain donating electron density through hyperconjugation, but this seems unlikely because both amines are primary.

My instructor said that the inductive effect of the carboxylic acid makes the NH3+ close to the oxygens unstable, but in solution it would be a negatively charged carboxyl group, making induction also seem unlikely.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the pKa for Propionic acid? How does that compare to lysine? Why the difference?

Comment: The alpha ammonium group can't make hydrogen bonds with the carboxylate group - they are pointing in the wrong direction and the connection is too tight.

Comment: @MaxW The pKa on Wikipedia is 4.88, which is less acidic than the COOH on lysine. Is this because of the alpha NH3+ stabilizing the conjugate base? What does this have to do with the acidity of the two amines?